# Is there any workaround to save csv with multiple sheets in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm currently working with a pandas data frame and need to save data via CSV for different categories.so I thought to maintain one CSV and add separate sheets to each category. **As per my research via CSV, we can't save data for multiple sheets. is there any workaround for this?** I need to keep the format as CSV(cant use excel)

Comment: you mean save multiple CSV files? sure, just create another file?

Comment: No same CSV. but multiple sheets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

A CSV file is just a text file, it doesn't have a standard facility for "multiple sheets" like spreadsheet files do.

You could save each "sheet" as a separate file, but that's about it.